# Moment Generating function of Multinomial Distribution, very confused

Tags: distributions, multinomial-distribution, moment-generating-function

I know somewhat similar questions have been asked but they all seem to have somewhat different answers and I'm kind of confused.

I am self learning statistics, and I have the following question that has been confusing me for hours. It is:

$\text{Let } X_1, X_2,.... X_{k-1} \text{ have a multinomial distribution. Find the MGF of } X_2, X_3,.... X_{k-1}  $

Okay - seems somewhat simple, probably. The formula for the multinomial distribution that I am used to working with is:

$$f(X_1 = x_1,... X_{k-1}=x_{k-1})=\frac{n!}{x_1!x_2!...x_{k-1}!x_{k}!}p_1^{x_1}p_2^{x_2}...p_{k-1}^{x_{k-1}}p_k^{x_k}$$

And since we can have it simply in terms of $X_1,... X_{k-1}$ and not including $X_k$, since we know that $x_k = n-x_1-x_2....x_{k-1}$ and similarliy that $p_k = 1-p_1-p_2....-p_{k-1}$ we can redefine this as

$$f(X_1 = x_1,... X_{k-1}=x_{k-1})=\frac{n!}{x_1!x_2!...x_{k-1}!(n-x_1....-x_{k-1})!}p_1^{x_1}p_2^{x_2}...p_{k-1}^{x_{k-1}}(1-p_1....-p_{k-1})^{n-x_1....-x_{k-1}}$$

**My Attempt:**

*Note: throughout this, I'm going to be putting bolded numbers next to things that I'm not sure are correct, so I'd be really grateful if you could address each one and let me know if my assumption is correct!*

To restate the problem:

$\text{Let } X_1, X_2,.... X_{k-1} \text{ have a multinomial distribution. Find the MGF of } X_2, X_3,.... X_{k-1}  $

So that means, we're looking for $M(0, t_2, t_3....t_{k-1})$, I believe, since we never deal with some sort of $t_k$ since our multinomial function is only a function of up to $X_{k-1}$ **(1)**. So that's going to be calculating

$$E(e^{t_2X_2 + t_3X_3 +.... +t_{k-1}X_{k-1}})$$

Since we're taking the expectation, we need to sum (not integrate since this is a pmf) over all possible nonzero values that X can take on, i.e the support of each $X_1, X_2, ... X_{k-1}$, where I write the support of $X_i$ as $S(X_i)$ In other words,

$$E(e^{t_2X_2+.... +t_{k-1}X_{k-1}})  =$$
$$\sum_{S(x_1)}...\sum_{S(x_{k-1})} e^{t_2x_2+.... +t_{k-1}x_{k-1}} \frac{n!}{x_1!x_2!...x_{k-1}!(n-x_1....-x_{k-1})!}p_1^{x_1}p_2^{x_2}...p_{k-1}^{x_{k-1}}(1-p_1....-p_{k-1})^{n-x_1....-x_{k-1}}$$

Now, we can move around the $e^{t_2x_2+.... +t_{k-1}x_{k-1}}$ into a product of exponentials, and move it in front of the factorial kind of thing

$$\sum_{S(x_1)}...\sum_{S(x_{k-1})}\frac{n!}{x_1!x_2!...x_{k-1}!(n-x_1....-x_{k-1})!} (e^{t_2x_2}....e^{t_{k-1}x_{k-1}})p_1^{x_1}p_2^{x_2}...p_{k-1}^{x_{k-1}}  (1-p_1....-p_{k-1})^{n-x_1....-x_{k-1}}$$

Now, we can combine these with our p's, *except* for the $p_1$ term, since there is no corresponding $e^{t_1x_2}$, and the last "$p_k$" = $(1-p_1....p_{k-1})$ term since there is also no corresponding exponential term.

$$\sum_{S(x_1)}...\sum_{S(x_{k-1})}\frac{n!}{x_1!x_2!...x_{k-1}!(n-x_1....-x_{k-1})!} \cdot p_1^{x_1} \cdot (p_2e^{t_2})^{x_2}...(p_{k-1}e^{t_{k-1}})^{x_{k-1}}  (1-p_1....-p_{k-1})^{n-x_1....-x_{k-1}}$$

We can display this a little nicer with some Pi notation,

$$\sum_{S(x_1)}...\sum_{S(x_{k-1})}\frac{n!}{x_1!x_2!...x_{k-1}!(n-x_1....-x_{k-1})!}\cdot p_1^{x_1} \cdot \prod_{i=2}^{k-1} (p_ie^{t_i})^{x_i} \cdot (1-p_1....-p_{k-1})^{n-x_1....-x_{k-1}}$$

That's the most I can seem to simplify this. I don't know how to simplify this further.

The answer on slader confuses me:

[image]

I have three questions.

1. What even is that notation for the binomial coefficient? Why are there dots in there? How is it equivalent to the fraction that I use?
2. How are they able to JUST have the terms under the pi product thing? Why don't they have the terms $p_1^{x_1}$ and $(1-p_1....p_{k-1})$ lying about? Did they cancel them somehow? Am I wrong to include them in the first place?
3. How in the HECK are the last two rows of the solution equal? How do they get to that last thing at the end?

My textbook gives me some hints, but I don't really understand where these definitions come from.
[image]

Sorry if any frustration shows through, but I'm really conufused and there seems to be a shortage of info on the web to help me out. I'm practically begging for someone to help me!

Thanks,
A

Comment: Those are multinomial coefficients, not binomial coefficients: $n\choose{a,b,c,d}$ means 
$\frac{n!}{a!b!c!d!}$. Also they don't have $(1-p_1-p_2-\cdots-p_{k-1})$ or $(n-x_1-x_2-\cdots-x_{k-1})$ because  there *are only* $x_1,\ldots,x_{k-1}$; there is no $x_k$, so $(n-x_1-x_2-\cdots-x_{k-1})=0$

Comment: Also, it doesn't help with understanding they did it, but I would do the $n=1$ case and then take advantage of the mgf of an independent sum being the product of the individual mgfs.

Comment: @ThomasLumley thank you! I didn't actually know those existed, silly me. Thank you for clarifying that.